# C# marshal array of structs to function in c dll as output parameter

Tags: c#, arrays, dll, struct, marshalling

I would like to call a function in a c dll, from my c# application, which takes a fixed array of structs as a function argument, and modifies the data.

```
[DllImport("my_c_program.dll",  CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int GetData([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,
                                            ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.Struct,
                                            SizeConst=4)]
                                 MyDataStruct[] myData);
```

I make a call to the function

```
   MyDataStruct [] myDataArrayOfStructs = new MyDataStruct[4];
   GetRangingMeasurementData(myDataArrayOfStructs);
```

And can confirm that the function receives the array and modifies the data, however, following completion of the function, the returned array is unchanged.

Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `In(), Out()` to the marshaling attributes? Also I don't think you need the `ArraySubType` and `SizeConst`.

Comment: We can't see what MyDataStruct looks like and the [MarshalAs] attribute doesn't do anything interesting.  Nobody ever got fired for being explicit in their declarations, use int GetData([In, Out] MyDataStruct[] data); so the pinvoke marshaller knows that it always has to copy the data back.

Comment: That works like a charm. Thanks very much.